# DynamoDb persistence model with extension data

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have model

```
class Person
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey("PK")]
    public string Id {get;set;}

    [DynamoDBProperty()]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

In my dynamoDb table there are many persons with different attributes, but `Name` is mandatory attribute in my system.

I want to get this kind of person from database:

```
{
    "PK":"123",
    "Name": "John",
    "Position": "Developer",
    "Address": "NY"
}
```

and map it to my persistent model, but except `Name` I also want to get all attributes that haven't been map.

So I suppose to extend my model like this:

```
class Person
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey("PK")]
    public string Id {get;set;}

    [DynamoDBProperty()]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public Dictionary<string, string> AllOtherProperties {get;set;}
}
```

Is there any chance to do this?

I know that when deserialize json we can use `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute, so I'm looking for similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe that it's possible to achieve via DynamoDBContext.
Unless all your additional properties are under "AllOtherPropertiesAttribute" (I doubt that this is the case, especially according your example).

But you may go on the level down and try low-level dynamodb client, which returns attribute map. In that case you'll be able to store other fields into a dictionary.

```
    var result = await client.GetItemAsync("persontable", new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        {  "PK", new AttributeValue { S = "MYID123" } }
    });

    var person = new Person
    {
        Id = result.Item["PK"].S,
        Name = result.Item["Name"].S,
        OtherAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    };

    foreach (var attribute in result.Item)
    {
        if (attribute.Key != "PK" && attribute.Key != "Name")
        {
            person.OtherAttributes.Add(attribute.Key, attribute.Value.S); // This code is handling only the case when attirubutes are on the top level and has string type. For more complex scenarios it should be extended additionally. 
        }
    }
```

The downside of this approach is that you'll need to handle mapping by your own and handle save operation in the same way. The code is hard to support, put still may be applicable in case of small amount of properties you handle (In your case Id and Name).